# How to add menu link wrapper in drupal 7?

Tags: menu, hyperlink, drupal-7, wrapper

I have a menu, one menu item looking like this:

```
<li>
  <a href="aaa">LINK TITLE</a>
</li>
```

And I want this:

```
<li>
  <a href="aaa">
    <div class="custom">LINK TITLE</div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Or this:

```
<li>
  <div class="custom">
    <a href="aaa">LINK TITLE</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function theme_menu_link(array $variables) {

  $variables['element']['#localized_options']['html'] = true;
  $variables['element']['#title'] = '<div class="custom">' . $variables['element']['#original_link']['link_title'] . '</div>';

return theme_menu_link($variables);
}
```